# jQuery background-image JSON issue, url("") append is empty

Tags: jquery, html, json

So I have the following code, and it all works perfectly fine EXCEPT the `.css('background-image')` change. You'll see that the `url("");` is empty. Not sure why and I was hoping maybe someone could take a quick look and let me know what may be wrong? I supplied just the code as everything else works aside from this one piece.

HTML(After the jQuery has appended it):

```
<td class="RarityBG" style="background-image: url("");">
   <img src="img/trinket/trinket01.png">
</td>
```

jQuery(note that the .html append works 100%):

```
    var trinketJSON
    $.getJSON('js/trinket.json', function (data) {
        trinketJSON = data;
        console.log(trinketJSON);

        $.each(trinketJSON, function(i, item) {
            $('<tr>').html(
                "<td class='RarityBG'><img src='" + trinketJSON[i].TrinketIMG + "' /></td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].TrinketName + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].Rarity + "</td><td>" + 
                trinketJSON[i].EffectOne + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectTwo + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectThree + "</td><td>"  
                + trinketJSON[i].SetBonus + "</td>").appendTo('#trinketsTable');
            $('.RarityBG').css('background-image', 'url(' + trinketJSON[i].RarityBG + ')');
            });
        });
```

JSON:

```
  {
    "TrinketIMG": "img/trinket/trinket01.png",
    "TrinketName": "Trinket 01",
    "Rarity": "Common",
    "RarityBG": "img/trinket/rarity_common.png",
    "EffectOne": "+4 ACC",
    "EffectTwo": "-1 SPD",
    "EffectThree": "",
    "SetBonus": ""
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're not wrapping `trinketJSON[i].RarityBG` in quotes. I'd start there and see if it likes your HTML better.

Comment: if you try `console.log(trinketJSON[i]);` in your `.each` loop, what do you get?

Also, rather than writing an inline style in dynamically created html, I prefer to have an existing css class and then adding the class to the element. It's easier to maintain anyway; especially if you have to repeat it later.

Comment: @Difster I get a log of all JSON items, so that works. It also shows my RarityBG items.

Comment: @JamesHill Ahh, I see exactly what you are referring to! Let me try. If that's it.. I'll be so mad haha.

Comment: @JamesHill, actually it looks like the quotes are there. I didn't realize it, but if you look at the HTML that it creates, it has the quotes: 
`<td class="RarityBG" style="background-image: url("");">`

For some reason it looks like the JSON isn't populating, the `trinketJSON[i].RarityBG`. I'm about to lose my mind over this!

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Welp, sorry.. I figured it out.. this is what the code needed to look like: 
`'<td style=\'background-image: url("' + trinketJSON[i].RarityBG + '");\'><img src="' + trinketJSON[i].TrinketIMG  + '" /></td><td>' + trinketJSON[i].TrinketName + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].Rarity + "</td><td>" + 
                trinketJSON[i].EffectOne + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectTwo + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectThree + "</td><td>"  
                + trinketJSON[i].SetBonus + "</td>").appendTo('#trinketsTable');`

Needed to have '' instead of "" and adding style=\ *code* \>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-working:

```
        $.each(trinketJSON, function(i, item) {
            $('<tr>').html(
                "<td class='RarityBG'><img src='" + trinketJSON[i].TrinketIMG + "' /></td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].TrinketName + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].Rarity + "</td><td>" + 
                trinketJSON[i].EffectOne + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectTwo + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectThree + "</td><td>"  
                + trinketJSON[i].SetBonus + "</td>").appendTo('#trinketsTable');
            $('.RarityBG').css('background-image', 'url(' + trinketJSON[i].RarityBG + ')');
            });
        });
```

Working:

```
        $.each(trinketJSON, function(i, item) {
            $('<tr>').html(
                '<td style=\'background-image: url("' + trinketJSON[i].RarityBG + '");\'><img src="' + trinketJSON[i].TrinketIMG  + '" /></td><td>' + trinketJSON[i].TrinketName + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].Rarity + "</td><td>" + 
                trinketJSON[i].EffectOne + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectTwo + "</td><td>" + trinketJSON[i].EffectThree + "</td><td>"  
                + trinketJSON[i].SetBonus + "</td>").appendTo('#trinketsTable');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get rid of `each` if don't need to loop through it everytime.

```
<script>
    var trinketJSON
    $.getJSON('js/trinket.json', function (data) {
        trinketJSON = data;
        console.log(trinketJSON);
        // just removed this for now
        $('.RarityBG').css('background-image', 'url(' + trinketJSON.RarityBG + ')');
            //console.log("RarityBG" + trinketJSON.RarityBG);
        });
    </script>
```

Above script will be able access all the json keys and will populate the url also. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. In this particular situation I will need to loop through, but this is a solid piece of info.